# bold to emphasize main points?

Tags: discussion, formatting

I've been using bold to emphasize the main point I'm looking for, so people can see that and then read the details more. Is this a good idea? Example: [How to not change title with winscp batch](https://superuser.com/questions/1386688/how-to-not-change-title-with-winscp-batch)

Comment: Asking in this circumstance, not all.

Comment: How is this circumstance unique such that the answers in the other question don't apply?

Comment: Because while it is asking if bold is okay, I'm asking if it is okay to be used in the manner I described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why that would be a problem. Selective bolding of your actual question, to make it stand out from "details" or diagnostics that are supplementary, is something I myself do.